# Nested hasMany eager loading Laravel function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

**Current logical setup:**

- A room can have many objects.
- An object can have many scores.

-- **The problem is that the objects may/may not have any scores.**

**Scenario:**
I want to retrieve only objects that have a number, based on the `room_id` I provide.

**Attempted:**

```
$audits = Room::where('id', $room_id)
            ->has('objects.scores')
            ->get();
```

What I'm finding is that it's returning all objects, even though only a couple of the objects actually have a score.

**Relationship (Rooms):**

```
  public function objects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Object');
    }
```

**Relationship (Objects):**

```
 public function scores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Scores');
    }
```

**Relationship (Scores):**

```
   public function object()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Object');
    }
```

How I can query in reverse? Or the correct way! I only want objects that have a score associated with them, and consequently anything related to them (rooms etc..)

Many thanks.

Comment: The dot notation for your nested relationship query looks okay; I feel like this should return correct results (only `Room`s that have an `Object` that has a `Score`. How do you define the `object` relationship in `Room`? And also, I wonder if this might be a good case for using a `hasManyThrough()` relationship?

Comment: @camelCase, I have added the Object relationship to the description.

Comment: What does "dd(Room::where('id', $room_id)->has('objects.scores')->toSql());" show?

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing relationship declaration in your objects model, you should have put

Relationship (Objects):

```
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Scores');
}
public function room()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Rooms');
}
```